# Alias Key with space like (my name) insted of (my_name) cause error while generating release key hash

Tags: android, hash, md5, firebase-authentication, signed

Here my problem is:
- Last week I had generated the signed apk and upload to playstore.
- I had implemented firebase auth in that apk but using debug key(debug md5).

- Now I want to generate released key hash(release md5) for this app, but due to my key alias name with space like(my name) instead of (my_name)cause a problem like [Illegal option: name ] and below.
- And now I knew that if I make alias name without space like (my_name), the release md5 hash key will be generated easily.

  ```
   keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias my name -keystore /home/bpn/Music/keystore.jks
  ```

  Illegal option:  name

keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

-rfc                            output in RFC style

-alias                   alias name of the entry to process

-keystore             keystore name

-storepass                 keystore password

-storetype           keystore type

-providername     provider name

-providerclass   provider class name

-providerarg               provider argument

-providerpath         provider classpath

-v                              verbose output

-protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands

Answer (score 11):

Put the name of the key alias in quotes, like this:

> keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias "my name" -keystore
>   /Path/to/keystore.jks

I made the experience that a space in the alias causes more troubles than it's worth. You can use the following command to change the alias if you like to. After you change the alias it's still possible to update your app in the Google Play Store.

> keytool -changealias -alias "ALIAS OLD" -destalias "ALIASNEW"
>   -keypass PASSWORD -keystore /Path/to/keystore.jks -storepass PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

Use **double quotation** for alias below is example.

jarsigner -verb
ose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystore.jks unsignedapp.apk "alias name"